# Shell Piping the data in middle of another command

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

If I need to have scripts like below:

```
find -name 'lib*.so' | xargs cp <files> ~/libs/.
```

Where < files > is the file which I found from the previous find command. Basically i want to pipe the data not just at the end but some where in the middle. (Some thing like $1 ???)

I understand I can have small sh file, where I can have this in a variable and use For loop & use that variable.... But what I want is simple one as I explained above. Where simple tasks can be accomplished easily.

Note: The script above is only a indication of type of Problem and the actual problem.

Let me know if this kind is possible.

Comment: Look for options to your command. For instance, `cp` has the `-t` option to specify the target directory. This way, you can still have the results of the `find` command piped at the end.

Comment: Note that the `-t` option is not standard in POSIX, but is a very useful addition to GNU `cp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand what you're trying to do here...

You can do this using find only.

```
find -name 'lib*.so' -exec cp {} ~/libs/ \;
```

Comment: That works, but copies one file per invocation of `cp`, which can be a bit expensive.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do copy

```
find -name 'lib*.so ' -print0 | xargs -r0 cp --target ~/libs/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using find only, without having to spawn `cp(1)` for each file by doing:

```
find -name 'lib*.so' -exec cp -t ~/libs {} +
```

Note that this only works with GNU cp and a POSIX 2008 compliant find, like GNU find.